# Git Commit Access denied Why?

Tags: 14.04, git

I am facing issue during git commit Please see the detailed information below.

```
git push origin master
```

Processing..

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false push -v --tags         origin master:master

Pushing to ssh://user11@192.168.100.76:29418/LiveProject.git

Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied
Access denied

FATAL ERROR: Network error: Connection reset by peer.
```

Please advise.

Comment: What's the output of `ssh -vvv -p 29418 user11@192.168.100.76`?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure that you can connect to remote , ping remote should succeed

   ping 192.168.100.76
2. Make sure that you have configure ssh credentials/certs properly
3. Make sure that the user have push permissions to remote

   read some help on how to add a certificate for ssh auth to remote git

   and add the remotes uri to your local repo configuration

check the output of this command whether you have configured the remote or not.

```
  $git remote -v
```

Comment: Can you please expand your answer a bit and explain how to do these three steps?

Comment: what is the output of `git remote -v`